# $1/4 + 1/ 9 + ... 1/n^2< 1$ induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

I have been trying this sum for long and do not know how to proceed.

Q. Prove using induction that $$\frac1 4 + \frac1 9 + ... + \frac 1 {n^2} < 1$$

A. By induction.

Let $$P(n) = \frac1 4 + \frac1 9 + ... + \frac 1 {n^2} < 1$$

Base Case, $P(2):\frac 1 4 < 1$, True.

Inductive Step: Assuming $P(n)$ is true

$$P(n+1) = \frac1 4 + \frac1 9 + ... + \frac 1 {n^2} + \frac 1 {n^2 + 2n +1}< 1$$

I am stuck now and don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those cases where proving something is most easily done by proving something stronger. For instance, you might be able to prove by induction that
$$
\frac14 + \frac19 + \cdots +\frac1{n^2} < 1-\frac1n
$$
which would directly imply
$$
\frac14 + \frac19 + \cdots +\frac1{n^2} < 1
$$
The big difference in the stronger version is that you actually get some wriggle room when you do the induction step, which makes it possible to actually complete the induction.

Comment: So now how do I proceed? Should I find the P(n+1)?

Comment: @DhruvSomani The induction hypothesis becomes 
$$
\frac14 + \frac19 + \cdots +\frac1{n^2} < 1-\frac1n
$$
and you want to prove
$$
\frac14 + \frac19 + \cdots +\frac1{n^2} +\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < 1-\frac1{n+1}
$$
which is solved by the standard "Apply the induction hypothesis and calculate" paradigm.

Comment: So I continue like this?$$1 - \frac 1 n + \frac 1 {(n+1)^2} < 1 - \frac 1 {n+1}$$ This would end up like this: $$ \frac 1 {n^2 + 2n +1} < \frac 1 {n^2+n}$$ Is this proof enough? I assume this would be so, since $n$ cannot be negative and $ 2n > n $ for all positive $n$.

Comment: @DhruvSomani That's all there is to it, yes. Unless you want to write $2n + 1 > n$ instead, for completeness.

Comment: Exceptionally thankful to you.

Comment: I'd be a bit more rigorous with how you write it out. I'd calculate out $1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and put it in a form with denominator $n(n+1)^2$. Then calculate out $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$ in a form with denominator $n(n+1)^2$. Then compare the two at the end. In your post, you start with the conclusion, and simplify to get an expression which we know to be true... it's a bit sloppy since you're starting with the conclusion.

Comment: I have a doubt. Can we really write $$P(n) = \frac1 4 + \frac1 9 + ... + \frac 1 {n^2} < 1$$ as $$1 - \frac 1 n$$?? This is because they aren't equal. You never know since adding it may increase the value much more than $$1- \frac 1 { n+1}$$

Comment: @DhruvSomani No, you have to set $P(n)$ to be
$$
\frac14+\cdots + \frac1{n^2} < 1-\frac1n
$$
and then once you're done with the proof note that $P(n)$ (which you have now proven for any $n$) implies 
$$\frac14 + \cdots + \frac1{n^2} < 1$$